# SSDT Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server connect throwing "Value cannot be null error"

Tags: ssis, ssas, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi, ssis-2017

I am trying to connect OLAP cube server from SSIS using script task(C# .net). I am getting following error

> "Value cannot be null".

I am using the SSDT 2017.

The same was working from BIDS 2008. But not working on the SSDT 2017.

```
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server server = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server();
server.Connect("localhost");
```

> Error Message : Value cannot be null. Inner Exception : null

Comment: Don't use a NULL value where the code doesn't allow NULL to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `localhost` with the `DataSource=localhost`.

*Example:*

```
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server server = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server();
server.Connect(@"DataSource=localhost");
```

**References**

- [Connect to an existing tabular server and database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tom/connect-to-existing-analysis-services-tabular-server-and-database)

---

I suggest refering to te following article for a step by step guide to connect to SSAS multidimensional database from Script Task:

- [Create SQL Server Analysis Services Partitions using AMO](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2796/create-sql-server-analysis-services-partitions-using-amo/)

Comment: I think the second part is the OP need +1

Comment: Replacing localhost with "DataSource=localhost" does not work for me. I had already tried giving complete connection string and well as you said in the above. But not working. somehow in the same machine with 2008 SSIS it was working. i am able to connect.